# How to start geth for whisper only without blockchain stuff?

Tags: go-ethereum, whisper

I'm writing a chat app on top of **Whisper**; the app is supposed to manage the lifecycle of the Ethereum node.

One way to build to is to use [wnode](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Diagnostic-Tool-wnode) in the background & communicate with it using stdout/stdin programmatically. However, I prefer to use the `web3.shh` API so I need an Ethereum/Whisper client that provides the RPC interface beside Whisper stuff.

[geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth) seems to fit. However, it seems to, by default, start blockchain stuff & other stuff while I only need it for Whisper. So:

1- How to start `geth` such that it provides absolutely zero blockchain stuff & only whisper stuff (+rpc)?

2- How to get it to be a *bootstrap* node for whisper & retrieve its `enode` url?

3- How to configure it to use other bootstrap nodes? Is the `--bootnodes` flag used for whisper?

Basically, I want to be able to do what's in the example [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Diagnostic-Tool-wnode) but using `geth`, with no unnecessary overhead:

```
> wnode -standalone -forwarder -ip=127.0.0.1:30379
my public key: 0x040ef7acd60781c336c52056b3782f7eae45be2063e591ac6b78472dc27ba770010bde445ffd2f3623ad656f3859e00d11ef518df4916c4d4e258c60b15f34c682 enode://15454fc65bbf0031155f4eee83fa732f1454c314e9f78ade9cba4d4a098d29edbf5431764ee65b200169025c3f900cacc3348a000dda7a8a0d9643d0b7618712@127.0.0.1:30379
Bootstrap Whisper node started

... Then, in another tab:

> wnode -test -boot=enode://15454fc65bbf0031155f4eee83fa732f1454c314e9f78ade9cba4d4a098d29edbf5431764ee65b200169025c3f900cacc3348a000dda7a8a0d9643d0b7618712@127.0.0.1:30379
............................
Whisper node started
Connected to peer.
............................
```

## Update

I haven't tried the accepted answer myself but I confirmed from the author that he/she tried it and the solution *seems* to be meeting all the requirements.

Comment: You can start geth --light  and  add --nodiscover tag, in this case  you will have minimal client useful for ssh transporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running Status's go server (in a docker image) will do what you want: no blockchain syncing, plus an exposed HTTP API interface that meets the JSONRPC standard.

Following these instructions worked for me:
https://status.im/technical/run_status_node.html

Namely

```
docker run --rm \
    -p 8545:8545 \
    -v $(pwd)/http-enabled.json:/config/config.json \
    statusteam/status-go:0.16.0 \
    -register \
    -log DEBUG \
    -c /config/config.json
```

Then test it with calls like

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8545" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"shh_newKeyPair","params":[],"id":1}'
```

#### Archive (Geth only)

My old answer, for completeness.
You can run `geth` with only the whisper `shh` module enabled and
`syncmode=light`. This doesn't exactly do what you wanted (it still syncs the blockchain)
but is more lightweight / faster than running a full node,
and more secure than giving access to the other API modules that you don't need or want to expose.

You can start with flags like this

```
geth --rinkeby --syncmode=light --rpcaddr=0.0.0.0 --shh --rpcapi=shh --rpc --rpcport 8547
```

There's no technical difference between mainnet and rinkeby messages, since whisper messages are ephemeral and not secured on-chain, but mainnet whisper messages won't get exchanged with rinkeby peers and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I haven't used `geth` for so long that I don't remember the question and that setting up to try out your suggestions would be costly. I also won't be able to mark as accepted in case it was not. If you have tried it and are sure it's correct, please tell me to mark it as accepted to guide future visitors.

Comment: Thanks for a response, I see you originally posted over a year ago (yikes). I found that the status-go server meets all of your requirements and just tried it out a few minutes ago. The few RPC methods I tried work fine.